# Прикрепление файла js

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет,есть такой вопрос,у меня на стороне бэка генерируется и сохраняется файл,и у меня есть страница,для прикрепления файла,можно ли при переходе на страницу сразу его прикрепить?

Comment: Что значит - прикрепить файл?

Comment: Ну файл у меня генерируется на бэке,и есть так называемая форма заявки,где пользователь прикрепляет файл,но мне нужно,чтобы при открытии формы файл сразу сам прикреплялся ,вот и думаю как это сделать)

Comment: мысль 1) в инпуте в пути к файлу указать `URL` 2) использовать blob/url/base64

Comment: Все равно повторю свой вопрос **Что значит - прикрепить файл?**. Что вы подразумеваете под словом **прикрепить**? Спрашиваю, потому что в устоявшемся лексиконе **прикрепить** обычно означает, что пользователь прикрепляет файл, находящийся на локальном компьютере пользователя в тег `<input type="file">`.

Comment: Нет,пользователь не должен прикреплять файл,файл уже отображается в инпуте загруженным без действий пользователя,можно ли как-то передать путь файла в инпут?